Within Dynamics 365 Online how to create records with related data from the UI
I Found a clear example of how to do it via the API: Link
But I cant seem to find any documentation or examples on using: Xrm.Page.data.entity.relatedEntities.add() to do the same thing.
I put together this based on the blog I found for doing this via the API.
Xrm.Page.data.entity.relatedEntities.add("contact_customer_accounts", 
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith"
    }
])

whilst creating a new Account record, I open the Developer Console and paste the statement, it accepted my input, but then nothing happened after I clicked save.
EDIT:
I found a way to achieve this, but its not the optimal result as it requires making an API call opposed to Microsoft handling it all in one.
The work around is to use the Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnPostSave() method.
Like this:
Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnPostSave(() => {
    // Get ID of the parent record
    var parentRecordId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    
    // Object holding data for the related record
    var relatedRecord = {
        "parentcustomerid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(" + parentRecordId.replace("{","").replace("}","") + ")",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith"
    };


    // Use Web API to create the related record
    Xrm.WebApi.createRecord("contact", relatedRecord)
        .then(
            function success(result) {
                // Handle success
                console.log("Related record created with ID: " + result.id);
            },
            function(error) {
                // Handle error
                console.log("Error creating related record: " + error.message);
            }
        );
});

Please let me know if anyone is aware how to get Xrm.Page.data.entity.relatedEntities.add() working as this would save an API call being made.

If you need to perform CRUD operations (like creating a record) inside the UI (so JavaScript client side) you need to use Xrm.WebApi
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi
I created a tool that works with the API that generate the correct Xrm.WebApi syntax:
Dataverse REST Builder
